# Any ideas...Prove that the centres of the circles circumscribing triangles $EBA$, $FBD$, and $GCA$ form an equilateral triangle...

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

**question**

Consider the rhombus $ABCD$ with centre $O$, with $\angle DAB < 60°$ and the equilateral triangle $ABE$ so that the points $E$ and $D$ are on either side of the line $AB$. The center circle $E$ and radius $AB$ intersect the line $AC$ at the points $F$ and $A$, and the line $BD$ at the points $G$ and $B$. Prove that the centres of the circles circumscribing triangles $EBA$, $FBD$, and $GCA$ form an equilateral triangle.

*drawing*

[image]

*idea*

We see that $\angle BGA \cdot 2=\angle BEA=60$, which means that $\angle BGA=30$

Because $ABCD$ is a rhombus, the diagonals are perpendicular $\implies \angle GOA=90$

Using the 30-angle theorem we can simply show that $OA \cdot 2 =GA=CA$

Because $OG$ is the perpendicular but also the median of the triangle $GCA \implies CG=GA $

From the congruences, we can show that $CGA$ is an equilateral triangle.

WE can show that $B$ isn't the center of the circumscribing circle, because $OA^2=OB \cdot OG$, which makes $BG=3k$ and $OK=k$

We also know that triangle $DFB$ is isosceles.

ALSO $BFAG$ is an writable quadrilateral

I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Use `\implies` for implication, and either `\times` or `\cdot` for multiplication.

Comment: @Trebor Sorry, for my messy writing. I will try to fix it! Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Trebor i edited it now! Is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the figure,

Note that $$\angle AEB= 60^{\text o} \implies \angle ALB =\angle AGB= 30^{\text o}$$
$$$$
\begin{align}
\angle CFB= \angle ALB & \implies \angle CFB = 30^{\text o} \\
 & \implies \angle CIB=60^{\text o}\\
& \implies \angle CIB = \angle AEB=60^{\text o} \\
& \implies E, A, I, B \; \;\mathrm{are \; concyclic.} \tag{1}
\end{align}

Similarly $\angle AJB = \angle AEB =60^{\text o} \implies E, A, B, J \; \;\mathrm{are \; concyclic.} \tag{2}$

$(1), (2) \implies E, A, I, B, J$ lie on the same circle.

Since $H$ is the center of circle $EAB$, $HI=HJ \; \mathrm{(radii)} \tag{3}$

Next observe that  $\angle IAJ = \angle KAJ = 90^{\text o}-60^{\text o}=30^{\text o}$

$\therefore \angle IHJ =2 \times \angle IAJ = 60^{\text o} \tag{4}$

$(3), (4) \implies $  $\Delta HIJ$ is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I wanna ask you why $\angle CFB=\angle ALB$?

Comment: $AFBL$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. The exterior angle $\angle CFB$ is equal to the interior opposite angle $\angle ALB.$

Comment: Another question. What is L in this drawing? You puted it without saying what is it.

Comment: @IonelaBuciu $L$ can be any point on $\overset{ \huge\frown}{AG}$. It is introduced because we want to use $\angle ALB=\frac{\angle AEB}{2}=30^{\text o}$ and $\angle CFB=\angle ALB$ to prove that $\angle CFB=30^{\text o}$. Looking back, there is no need to introduce $L$. $\angle AGB=30^{\text o}$ and $\angle CFB=\angle AGB$  serves the same purpose.